# first tab content displayed in second tab using Tabhost android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am using TabHost.On load i have set the second tab to be the default tab. I works fine but along with second tab content the first tab contents are also shown. How to remove the first tab content. This is shown only on the default second tab and not the first tab.

I have tried the following code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Inflate the layout
        setContentView(R.layout.tabs_viewpager_layout);

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;


        // Initialise the TabHost
        this.initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); //set the tab as per the saved state
        }
        // Intialise ViewPager
        this.intialiseViewPager();
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
    }
```

my initialiseTabHost function

```
private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {

    mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    TabInfo tabInfo = null;
    TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.info_icon)), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab1", Info.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);

    TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.search_icon)), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab2", Search.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);


    TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_icon)), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab3", Home.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(2); 
    TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab4").setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.member_icon)), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab4", Profile.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
   mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

}
```

Can someone pls help me with this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

**

Main Activity :

```
   package com.example.tab;
   import android.os.Bundle; import android.widget.TabHost;
   import android.app.TabActivity; import android.content.Intent;







   public class MainActivity extends TabActivity{   TabHost tb1;
@Override   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            tb1=getTabHost();

tb1.addTab(tb1.newTabSpec("first").setIndicator("first1").setContent(new    Intent(MainActivity.this,first.class)));    
tb1.addTab(tb1.newTabSpec("second").setIndicator("second").setContent(new    Intent(MainActivity.this,second.class)));  




    }


   }
   first.class
   package com.example.tab;
   import android.app.Activity; import android.os.Bundle;
   public class first extends Activity{

@Override   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        //    TODO Auto-generated method stub       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        } }
   second.class
   package com.example.tab;
   import android.app.Activity; import android.os.Bundle;
   public class second extends Activity{

@Override   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        //    TODO Auto-generated method stub       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main1);
        }    }
```

Comment: register both first and second activity in manifest.xml and create two xml file in layout folder for first and second class view.

Comment: I am using fragment. I think that must be causing a problem.

Comment: if you are using fragment then share your code with me . i will solve your problem in fragment.my email id is meashu29@gmail.com